# Using @continueSpan does not add log values in spring sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Using @continueSpan does not add log values in spring sleuth.
I am using @continueSpan annotation but could not find a way to add log value for span in it. any references will help.

```
@ContinueSpan(log = "submitStream")
  public IngestionResponse submitStream(final InputStream inputStream,
      @SpanTag("ProducerName") @PathVariable String producerName,
      @SpanTag("HttpHeaders") @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
    LOGGER.info("[Upload to Stream]: Begin");
    final IngestionResponse ingestionResponse = ingestionService
        .ingestInputStream(inputStream, producerName, httpHeaders);
    String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());
    LOGGER.info("[Upload to Stream]: Completed");
    return ingestionResponse;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the two things:
- Create a new class with an annotated method, register its instance as bean and delegate calls to it at the beginning and end of the method call
- inject as a bean and manually call the `SpanCustomizer` interface and call annotate on it to annotate a span with a log

Comment: First approach looks like aspectJ  if i am not mistaken. Second approach i used span.annotate("log"); but it again adds log as key and how to assign it a log value

Comment: Logs don't have values. They have a key and a timestamp. If you want a key value pair you have to use tags